# Blank Parameter Panel in Crystal Reports Viewer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm building a web based (ASP .NET) application to display Crystal Reports. The reports itself have been build in Crystal Reports XI and I'm working in Visual Studio 2010. It's working but the Parameter Panel visible on the left of the report is blank, eg. it does not display any parameters even though the report has a few of them and the user is prompted to enter their values before the report is generated. I've found some information that this might be caused by an old version of Crystal Reports (XI) used to produce those reports and, indeed, a test report written in Visual Studio 2010 has its parameters shown correctly.

My question is: How can I make this to work without rewriting the reports once again? I tried to open up an existing report in Visual Studio and saving it, it gave me a warning that this the current version of the report is newer than the previous one, however it didn't solve the issue. Any ideas?

[image: parameterPanel]

Comment: Will you post a picture of the situation, please?

Comment: Sure, just added an image. If you read my answer to this question, you'd noticed that I found a solution to this problem, which although not perfect, works. My current question is: Is it possible to edit parameter's field 'Show on (Viewer) Panel' using Crystal Reports' .NET API instead of doing that in Designer (if so I could simply write a code to loop through all the fields and change their properties)? I searched for that in the documentation, but could not find anything relevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution to this problem (although it's not ideal). Basically, in Crystal Reports => 2008 or Crystal Reports for Visual Studio, by right - clicking on a parameter field we can choose Edit and then the 'Show on (Viewer) Panel' option (not available in Crystal Reports XI). Setting this to Editable or Read Only will show this parameter in the Parameter Panel (default is 'do not show'). If anybody has a better idea (better than editing all of the reports) then I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically change each parameter's panel settings.

You will need to enumerate the ParameterFields collection, changing each parameter's ParameterFieldUsage2 property:

```
string fileName = null;

ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
reportDocument.Load(fileName, CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault);

foreach (CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField parameterField in reportDocument.ParameterFields)
{
  parameterField.ParameterFieldUsage2 = ParameterFieldUsage2.ShowOnPanel;
}

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
```

Comment: Thanks, where would I place this code? I tried adding this to my Default.aspx.cs file in various places but it doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: I'm using c# so my code is slightly different, but I can't get it to work: ParameterFields fields = rptDoc.ParameterFields; ParameterField f = fields[0]; f.ParameterFieldUsage2.ShowOnPanel;

Comment: I'm getting the following error while trying this code: Error 2 Property or indexer 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ParameterFieldDefinition.ParameterFieldUsage2' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Thanks craig, but still getting an error, this time: System.NotSupportedException: Not Supported. in this line of code:  parameterField.ParameterFieldUsage2 = ParameterFieldUsage2.ShowOnPanel;

Answer (score 0):

If report is designed in previous version, parameters VALUE OPTIONS "Show on (Viewer) Panel"  are set to "Do not Show"; thats why parameters are not shown in panel. to solve this.
Just edit every parameter and set this property accordingly
1. Do Not Show
2. Editable
3. Read Only

Answer (score 0):

I was able to suppress the parameters panel at run time using this code:

```
crViewer.ToolPanelView = ToolPanelViewType.None;
```

Hope that keeps someone else from wasting an hour on this  :-)