# How to block the enter parameter value prompt from crystal report?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

How to block the enter parameter value prompt from crystal report

Comment: You need to elaborate on the context.  When it this occurring?  In your application?  At what point?  Do you want to prevent all parameter display or are the parameters being displayed after you've supplied a value?

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647611/blank-parameter-panel-in-crystal-reports-viewer

Comment: already try all codes from google but it is not working

Comment: didn't understand your issue

Comment: the parameter field in CR is set from c#, but the prompt is asking for parameter value. How to block this prompt?